# real example of using xmlns?

Tags: xml, xpath

I am wondering anyone can give me an example of the real usage of xmlns? In XPath?

Comment: what do you consider "real usage". What would be "unreal" usage?

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for explanation and a complete example.

Comment: considering adding more detail to the question if the answers below are not what you were expecting.

Answer (score 2):

I assume that what you want is to access a node that is part of a different namespace than the default.

Given the following XML:

```
<root xmlns:x="http://www.example.com" xmlns:y="http://www2.example.com">
  <test>
    <x:child y:attr="hey" />
  </test>
</root>
```

If you wanted to select the `child` element which is part of the `x` namespace, all you have to do is use its full name in your XPath expression:

```
//test/x:child
```

It works for attributes too:

```
//test/x:child/@y:attr
```

Answer (score 0):

**I guess that the most popular XML vocabulary in a namespace is XHTML:**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <body>
  <h1>Hello</h1>
 </body>
</html>
```

The way to write an easily understandable XPath expression selecting the `h1` element is:

1. Register in your XPath engine a namespace binding some prefix (say "x") to the XHTML namespace ("http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml").
2. Use this XPath expression:

   /x:html/x:body/x:h1